# Display only 25 results but bring back the full count of results sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, resultset, rowcount

Is it possible to have the result set of a stored procedure limited to 25 results, but also return the total number of results (not limited)? This stored procedure is used in a search page on a web application, so we have paged results (displaying 25 results per page), but need the `@@rowcount` to display 'Your results returned ___' results.

I've tried the obvious approaches like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [derived table containing the search query]
```

but due to data structure, the number of rows in participating tables, the `COUNT(*)` is taking longer than the query itself.

I apologize in advance for the formatting sticklers out there, still very new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `WITH common_table_expression`.

```
WITH ResultSet AS
(
    select CustomerID,CompanyName, ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by CompanyName asc) as RowNumber from Customers
)
select CustomerID,CompanyName,(Select Max(RowNumber) From ResultSet) AS TotalCount from ResultSet
where RowNumber > 0 and RowNumber < 25
```

In this case `CompanyName` would be sorting field and you can calculate the `max` `RowNumber` then apply pagination on it.

Another option is

```
declare @pageIndex int = 1
declare @pageCount int = 25
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName,COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CompanyName
OFFSET ( @pageIndex-1 ) * @pageCount ROWS
FETCH NEXT @pageCount ROWS ONLY
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8b0c/1)

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thanks @Stormcloak!! Admittedly a bit embarrassed; I didn't realize you can do a COUNT(*) OVER(), I thought including a COUNT required a GROUP BY clause. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you query the Count not from the derived table but from the original tables, and only get only the count that should be faster than from a derived table. You can then store that in an output parameter.

Other then that I don't see another way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, @Dingo. Unfortunately the way the SP is written that's pretty difficult. Was really hoping there was a way to set the option "discard results after execution" using a T-SQL command, that way the query would look like this: --T-SQL change to discard results
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
   col1,
   col2,
  FROM MyTable 
 ) X
ORDER BY X.col1 DESC 
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS TotalHi
--undo T-SQL change to discard results 

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
   col1,
   col2,
  FROM MyTable 
 ) X
ORDER BY X.col1 DESC 
OFFSET  0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY

Answer (score 0):

so why not do:

```
declare @numrows int;
SELECT @numrows = Count(*) FROM sys.databases;
PRINT @numrows; -- or assign to output param
```